# OWIN - Selfhosting WebApi without specific port

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, localhost, owin, self-hosting

Is it possible to selfhost a WebApi service without specifying the local port like this:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http://localhost:9000")
```

I think it can be troublesome in deployement to customers (e.g. firewall problems or conflicts with other services which occupy the same port).

I have found nothing. Every tutorial/example uses the port.

Without Owin it is possible with a WebApi service.

Edit:
I want that the service doesn't use any port at all. The server should run "inmemory" like it is done in this blog:
 [asp-net-web-api-in-memory-hosting/](http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/asp-net-web-api-in-memory-hosting/)

Comment: Port is required for every connection, if you wont specify it, it will just use default(80 for http, 443 for https)

Comment: You can do an in-memory host without creating a TCP/IP connection and therefore you will not need a port, but then you will not be able to do cross process requests.  If you only want to do in-process requests then web-api can do that no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly this is a solution:
[owin-memory-integration-testing](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/12/owin-memory-integration-testing/)

It's in the Microsoft.Owin.Testing package.

> This will allow us to create an in-memory server, which will accept
>   HTTP requests and issues HTTP responses without touching the network
>   stack (entirely in process), which is both very efficient and
>   extremely fast.

Comment: If you want in-memory, then you don't even need to get Owin involved.  Just wire up a HttpClient to a web api HttpServer.

Comment: But than the routing which is in Startup wont be configured or am I wrong? If that is the case then I have to configure the Routes at two different places.

Comment: I always create a static method  e.g. MyApi.Register(HttpConfiguration config) so that I can re-use the config setup regardless of what host I use.  However, technically, you don't need the StartUp class anymore if you are only going to do in-memory hosting of a web api.

Answer (score 1):

Move that string to the `web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="_API_URL" value="http://localhost:9000">
</appSettings>
```

Then you can use it in your code:

```
Microsoft.Owin./*...*/(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["_API_URL"]);
```

Any settings in the config file can then be transformed during, or after, deployment without requiring a code change or rebuilding.  Let the "IT Admin" handle the firewall.

Comment: That could be a solution if I have to use a port. But I search for a solution where the service runs "inmemory" without using any port.